# SailsJS calling two Service methods with the one Controller action

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I am fairly new to learning full-stack development, specifically the backend side of things, and am trying to get this asynchronous Nodejs stuff figured out.

I have some backend actions I need to complete upon the submission of a forgot password form. Basically the controller action looks like this (*which I know is definitely done the wrong way*):

```
forgot: function (req, res) {
    var token = "febfoebfoui38383303cnc";
    var userEmail = req.body.email;
    var host = req.headers.host;

    AuthService.saveResetPasswordValues(token, userEmail, function (err, savedRecord) {
        if (err) { return res.send(404, '\n\nerror occurred\n\n'); }
        return res.json(savedRecord);
    });

    AuthService.sendForgotPasswordEmail(token, userEmail, host, function (err, message) {
        if (err) { return res.send(404, '\n\nerror occurred\n\n'); }
        return res.json(message);
    });
},
```

Each service does something to help the password reset email get sent out.

```
saveResetPasswordValues: function (token, userEmail, cb) {
    var expiration = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour
    User.update({ email: userEmail },
        { resetPasswordToken: token,
            resetPasswordExpires: expiration})
        .exec(function (err, user) {
            if (err) { return cb({ status: 404, message: 'Could not find user with that email address' }); }
            return cb(err, user);
        });
},

sendForgotPasswordEmail: function (token, userEmail, host, cb) {
    var htmlMessage =
        '<h4>You are receiving this because you (or someone else) have requested the reset of the password for your account.</h4>' +
        '<p>Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:</p>' +
        "<p><a href='http://" + host + '/reset/' + token + "'> Link to password reset </a></p>" +
        '<p>If you did not request this, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged.</p>';

    var emailInfo = {
        to: userEmail,
        from: "customerservice@smallchangeproj.com",
        subject: "Small Change Project Password Reset",
        message: htmlMessage,
        fromName: "Small Change Project"
    };

    .... some code for sending the email ...

     return cb(null, 'email has been sent');

}
```

At the end the user is supposed to get an email like this below:

> You are receiving this because you (or someone else) have requested
>   the reset of the password for your account.
>
> Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to
>   complete the process:
>
> [Link to password reset](http://www.google.com)

Surprisingly this code does work, but its spits out a bunch of ugly errors - telling me that I don't know how asynchronous callbacks work ;)

```
error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response: 
 Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:690:11)
    at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:133:22)
    at ServerResponse.res.set.res.header (/home/zacharyhustles/smallChangeAPI/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:577:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.send (/home/zacharyhustles/smallChangeAPI/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:142:12)
    at ServerResponse.res.json (/home/zacharyhustles/smallChangeAPI/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:223:15)
    at /home/zacharyhustles/smallChangeAPI/api/controllers/UserController.js:123:15
    at /home/zacharyhustles/smallChangeAPI/api/services/AuthService.js:50:4
    at Object.module.exports.simpleSendEmail (/home/zacharyhustles/smallChangeAPI/api/services/EmailService.js:48:12)
    at Object.bound [as simpleSendEmail] (/home/zacharyhustles/smallChangeAPI/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
    at Object.module.exports.sendForgotPasswordEmail (/home/zacharyhustles/smallChangeAPI/api/services/AuthService.js:46:16)
    at Object.bound [as sendForgotPasswordEmail] (/home/zacharyhustles/smallChangeAPI/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
    at Object.module.exports.forgot (/home/zacharyhustles/smallChangeAPI/api/controllers/UserController.js:121:15)
    at bound (/home/zacharyhustles/smallChangeAPI/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
    at routeTargetFnWrapper (/home/zacharyhustles/smallChangeAPI/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:179:5)
    at callbacks (/home/zacharyhustles/smallChangeAPI/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
    at param (/home/zacharyhustles/smallChangeAPI/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11) [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.]
```

What is the proper way to do this? I would like to still separate out the logic into two service methods...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error message already suggests, you are not allowed to send another response to the browser after you already have sent one, because in the classic request-response cycle of a web page request the browser only accepts one response per request.

You have to put the call of the second service function into the callback of the first service function and send the results of the service helpers in a combined object, e.g. like this:

```
    forgot: function (req, res) {
        var token = "febfoebfoui38383303cnc";
        var userEmail = req.body.email;
        var host = req.headers.host;

        AuthService.saveResetPasswordValues(token, userEmail, function (err, savedRecord) {
            if (err) { return res.send(404, '\n\nerror occurred\n\n'); }

            AuthService.sendForgotPasswordEmail(token, userEmail, host, function (err, message) {
                if (err) { return res.send(404, '\n\nerror occurred\n\n'); }
                // make sure to adapt your client logic for this response
                return res.json({savedRecord: savedRecord, message: message);
            });
        });
    },
```

The general conclusion with asynchronous callbacks is, if you have a function call that is dependant on the result of a previous call, you have to nest the second call always into the callback of the previous one, so they get called in the correct order and the second call can access the result of the first one.

If you want to send results of several asynchronous functions in one response, just nest the function calls so you have access to all results in the final deepest callback.